# How many different field homomorphisms can we have between any two given fields?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

How many field homomorphisms can we have between any two given fields? That is, if $A$ and $B$ are fields, what can we say about the cardinality of $\text{Hom}(A,B)$? I don't know much abstract algebra so I apologize if the answer is obvious. I got curious when thinking about whether the only field homomorphism $\mathbb{R} \rightarrowtail \mathbb{C}$ is the obvious one.

Comment: I'm assuming that you are talking about non-trivial homomorphisms.

Comment: What would a trivial homomorphism be? I believe field homomorphisms are always injective.

Comment: There are uncountably many field homomorphisms from the real to the complex numbers, coming from postcomposing with the uncountably many automorphisms of the complex numbers.

Comment: Thanks! Say we are complexifying vector spaces or Lie algebras over the real numbers. Does anything depend on which particular extension $\mathbb{R} \rightarrowtail \mathbb{C}$ we pick? Or is it all the same as if we use the standard extension?

Comment: A mapping that sends all elements in $\mathbb{R}$ to 0 is a field homomorphism.

Comment: @ಠ_ಠ: yes, you should pick the standard embedding. There are embeddings that don't make $\mathbb{C}$ two-dimensional over $\mathbb{R}$. And the only embedding that is continuous wrt the usual topologies is the usual one.

Comment: @Q the Platypus: this is only true with the convention that ring homomorphisms don't send units to units. This is a convention I've only seen in one or two textbooks (Herstein, maybe?) and, as far as I know, it is not the convention used by most authors and/or in the literature. (For example, in algebraic geometry, when people talk about the functor of points of a commutative ring in terms of commutative ring homomorphisms, they are always using homomorphisms that send units to units.)

Comment: Thanks Qiaochu! That's very interesting that you can have embeddings that don't make $\mathbb{C}$ two-dimensional over $\mathbb{R}$. Is there any particular example I could read about? It seems very strange to me (although admittedly my algebra background is weak).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only reasonable upper bound I know in general is the cardinality of the vector space of linear maps between the fields. (They must have the same characteristic for there to be any maps between them, so must both be vector spaces over $\mathbb{Q}$ or $\mathbb{F}_p$ for some prime $p$.)

For the case of $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$ there are $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$ automorphisms of $\mathbb{C}$, and the only automorphisms that fix $\mathbb{R}$ are the identity and complex conjugation, so any pair of automorphisms that aren't equal or aren't related by complex conjugation will send the usual copy of $\mathbb{R}$ to two different copies of $\mathbb{R}$. Hence there are (at least) $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$ homomorphisms $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}$, which incidentally is also the cardinality of the vector space of ($\mathbb{Q}$-)linear maps between them.

Answer (score 1):

1. $A$ and $B$ must have the same characteristic.
2. An element $f\in Hom(A,B)$ is injective, thus $B$ is an extension of $A$.
3. Suppose that $B$ is an algebraic extension of $A$, they have the same algebraic closure $C$, each morphism $f:A\rightarrow B$ can be extended to a morphism $f':C\rightarrow C$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_extension_theorem

So if $k$ is $Z/p$ if the characteristic is $p$ or $Q$ if the characteristic is zero. For an algebraic extension $ B$ of $A$,  the elements of $Gal(C:k)$ which fixes $B$ acts transitively on $Hom(A,B)$.